# BigQuery Group By and If expression

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having trouble rationalising something in BigQuery. Basically I am having trouble with the full group by while using StandardSQL. I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d', DATETIME(tstmp)) AS f_timestamp,
  IF(tstmp < '2016-11-01 00:00:00', 10, 15) AS rate
FROM
  `table`
GROUP BY
  f_timestamp
```

The result I am trying to achieve looks like this:

```
f_timestamp         rate     
2016-11-02          15
2016-10-30          10
```

But BigQuery complains about the `tstmp` field, which is in the `IF` statement:

`SELECT list expression references column tstmp which is neither grouped nor aggregated at`

Including it in the Group By produces a completely different result, since it groups it on timestamp level, which is not what I need.

Any ideas on how to achieve the result I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d', DATETIME(tstmp)) AS f_timestamp,
  MAX(IF(tstmp < '2016-11-01 00:00:00', 10, 15)) AS rate
FROM
  `table`
GROUP BY
  f_timestamp
```